# MathJax: Can't render \begin{cases}...\end{cases} using Jekyll

Tags: html, markdown, mathjax

We use MathJax on [our course website](https://makeabilitylab.github.io/physcomp/electronics/leds.html), which is implemented in Jekyll and hosted on GitHub pages. For small, straightforward equations, MathJax works great but I've never been able to get even slightly more complicated equations to work. I've spent many hours investigating and experimenting, so I thought I'd finally ask here.

For example, the following fails to render:

```
$$
S_{i} =
\begin{cases}
    X_{1} & \text{if i = 1}\\
    \alpha \cdot X_{i} + (1 - \alpha) \cdot S_{i-1} & \text{if i $>$ 1}
\end{cases}
$$
```

The rendered output in the web browser is literally blank.

When I look at the rendered html, I see:

```
<p>
<span class="MathJax_Preview" style="color: inherit; display: none;"></span>
<span id="MathJax-Element-5-Frame" class="mjx-chtml MathJax_CHTML" tabindex="0" data-mathml="
    <math
        xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML&quot; />" role="presentation" style="font-size: 113%; position: relative;">
        <span id="MJXc-Node-149" class="mjx-math" aria-hidden="true">
            <span id="MJXc-Node-150" class="mjx-mrow"></span>
        </span>
        <span class="MJX_Assistive_MathML" role="presentation">
            <math
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
            </math>
        </span>
    </span>
    <script type="math/tex" id="MathJax-Element-5">% 
        <![CDATA[ S_{i} = \begin{cases} X_{1} & \text{if i = 1}\\ \alpha \cdot X_{i} + (1 - \alpha) \cdot S_{i-1} & \text{if i $>$ 1} \end{cases} %]]>
    </script>
</p>
```

I'm not a LaTeX expert so I often write equations (or at least check them) in online editors like https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php or OverLeaf. They render fine there.

---

**UPDATE:** I took the advice in this thread and asked elsewhere. Specifically, the MathJax user group ([link](https://groups.google.com/g/mathjax-users/c/YKftPSymXOA/m/eynczyJ1AQAJ)) and they provided the answer, which is the solution described in detail [on GitHub](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/2377#issuecomment-602708309).

Comment: mathjax is off-topic here. It uses latex syntax but it is not latex.

Comment: Thanks Ulrike. Do you have suggestion of a better place to ask? I saw some MathJax questions on this StackExchange before posting.

Comment: And you'll see the same comment every tlme. Depending on how you load mathjax it will support different features. See the mathjax homepage

Comment: The recommended place to go for MathJax help is [MathJaX Help Forums](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mathjax-users)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's off-topic.

Comment: that is showing mathjax expanded text, did you select and use "view selection source" as it doesn't look like the html that I would expect jekyll to write, as you would see from  "view page source"

Comment: you might want to put `{% raw %}` ... `{% endraw %}`  around your math see https://mathml-refresh.github.io/discussion-papers/mjtest